# Elegant way to use Cupy-Numpy together

Tags: python, numpy

I am building a Python package in which definitions/methods are using Numpy. I want to give my future users to choose Cupy or Numpy as they load the package. What is the elegant or let me say correct way to do that?

To give little bit more context; my library lives in a folder called `mynewlibrary` and there is only one file inside the folder; `__init__.py`. Inside the `__init__.py` currently, I import both as follows.

```
import numpy as np_cpu
import cupy as np

def compute(a):
    return np.pi*a
```

How do I set np to numpy or to cupy during `import mynewlibrary` on demand?

Comment: What do you mean exactly `on demand`? add an example.

Comment: Assume user import mynewlibrary but while importing chooses either numpy or cupy to be loaded.

Comment: Create another module `config.py` that contains only one variable `use_numpy = True #or False` and import it in your `mynewlibrary` module

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I think I spoke too soon. If I do that, I don't necessarily need a `config.py`, one can set a variable inside `__init__.py` as well. I am hoping to find a solution where library is imported than I call some sort of init definition from library to choose if I use `Numpy` or `Cupy` across the library. I am hoping that this is a better description of the need here.

Comment: In the other scripts in my library, whenever I need `np`, I import it as `from mynewlibrary import np`.

Answer (score 0):

One naive approach is to use a dummy module `config.py` that contains a boolean variable:

```
# config.py
use_numpy=True
```

In your `__init__.py` file, import `config.py` and check for the value of `use_numpy`:

```
import config

if config.use_numpy:
   import numpy as np
else:
   import cupy as np

def compute(a):
    return np.pi*a
```

If you want to use `cupy`, set `use_numpy=False` in `config.py`.